# d3.js - how to actualize the graph data? transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am trying to learn d3.js (with no JavaScript background) so I created a simple [scatter plot](https://jsfiddle.net/royezqzj/).

Now, I am looking for how to render that graph with random data, each time the user click on the `Next` button.

In the link above, there is what I tried so far.

I know it's a very newbie question and there is thousands of example but I am looking for an explained solution (not just code).  Thanks

PS: Please change the external ressource to [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js) if the graphs won't show up.

Comment: Well, you generate new data and either remove all previous points and add the new ones or use D3's [data binding](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/). Do you have a specific question on any of this?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I removed the previous data using `svg.selectAll("circle").remove()` but nothing happened

Comment: You're appending a new SVG each time, so you'd need to remove that. You also need to give all arguments to the `scatter()` function when you call it. https://jsfiddle.net/royezqzj/2/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can you post a solution as an answer (with some code)? thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the changed jsfiddle? Does that solve your problem?